# XCode error EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using sqlite3 + table + tab bar

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2, exc-bad-access

I have a class ClsDatabase that is called to save / retrieve data. 
There are also 2 views. The 2nd view have table that will display information based on what ClsDataBase retrieved. A tab-bar controls the 2 views.

It can load initially with the 1st view shown. However, when I select the 2nd view, it stops at main.m's

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([TestTabBarAppDelegate class]));
```

with error message: EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I tried create another project but without ClsDatabase and just print some dummmy values in table, and it works. Not sure if its because of the class ClsDatabase

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "TestTabBarAppDelegate.h"
#import "TestTabBarFirstViewController.h"
#import "TestTabBarSecondViewController.h"

@implementation TestTabBarAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_tabBarController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[TestTabBarFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestTabBarFirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[TestTabBarSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestTabBarSecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

(2nd view).h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "ClsDatabase.h"

@interface TestTabBarSecondViewController : UIViewController<UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>{
    NSArray *arrDebtor;
    ClsDatabase *dbDebtor;
}

@end
```

(2nd view.m)

```
#import "TestTabBarSecondViewController.h"

@implementation TestTabBarSecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Second", @"Second");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    NSString *strSql;
    dbDebtor = [[ClsDatabase alloc] initWithDbName:@"Debt"];
    arrDebtor = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    strSql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Debtor"];
    arrDebtor = [dbDebtor ReturnQueryArray:strSql];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section             {
    if ([arrDebtor count] == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return [arrDebtor count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{  
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Debtor";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if ([arrDebtor count] == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
            cell.textLabel.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No tables or records found"];
            return cell;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        NSMutableDictionary *dictDebtor = [arrDebtor objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text  = [dictDebtor valueForKey:@"Name"];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried to use NSZombieEnabled to track this type of error, the apps just quit before zombie message, when I clicked the 2nd tab.

Comment: You are posting too much code. Try to cut down on it and just show the parts that you suspect may contain the issue.

Comment: yup. already reduced to the minimal...sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing lot's of things in code that should be done with IB and storyboarding.

Your logic in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will fail on the first row, when `indexPath.row` is `0` and your `arrDebtor` is empty and your cell has not been created yet. That would explain the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.